# Three.js: Add Image to Texture Bottom in 6 Cube Panorama as a Hotspot

Tags: javascript, three.js, 360-panorama

I am using [this panorama](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=panorama#webgl_panorama_cube) as a base for my project. Now I want to add a small image (circle) to the bottom of one chosen texture as if this is a hotspot on the panorama floor that will respond to user click. Please see the image below with 2 circles on the floor:

[image]

I tried the following code to add image to one of 6 textures in panorama:

```
var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
loader.load('img/test-circle-sample.png', function ( texture ) {
    var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 1, 1 );
    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map : texture, opacity : 1, side : THREE.DoubleSide, transparent : true } );
    var sprite = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    scene.add(sprite);
});
```

While it seems to actually load the image, the circle is far from looking like on the picture above. It is very wide, even though its size is 256 pixels and is positioned around the camera - you can see it on very top, bottom, sides, but not in front of you as a small circle. I played around with these settings but they did not work well:

```
sprite.position.set(0,-360,0);
sprite.rotateOnAxis(  new THREE.Vector3( 1, 0, 0 ), THREE.Math.degToRad(90) );
sprite.scale.set( 1, 1, 1 );
```

I need help with positioning the image in front of camera for any chosen side (or angle) and keep it stuck to the floor, so dragging camera would adjust how this image looks (skewed effect based on angle).

Update: I created this Plunker but image now not seen at all. 
http://plnkr.co/edit/KS6dVMn5AIEaXr143Jv3?p=preview

Comment: Any live code example of your approach?

Comment: Yes! See update above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I understand your question - as I understand, you want the hot spot to be placed below the camera (ie at the viewers feet)? If so, it seems you're transforming the hot spot incorrectly, which may be the reason it appears warped.

I took a copy of your live demo at http://plnkr.co/edit/KS6dVMn5AIEaXr143Jv3?p=preview and made some alterations to get the hot spot to display correctly.

Try and update the way you transform and rotate your hot spot, as shown in the following code:

```
function addHotSpot(scene){

    THREE.ImageUtils.crossOrigin = '';
    var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
    loader.load('https://i.imgur.com/vU163P4.png', function ( texture ) {
        var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 1, 1 );
        var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { 
            map:texture, 
            opacity : 1, 
            side : THREE.DoubleSide, 
            transparent : false  // Note, I also set this to false.
        } ); 

        var sprite = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );


        // Offset the hotspot so it is below the view origin [Updated]
        sprite.position.set(0,-5,5);

        // Compute the rotation for the hotspot, 90deg around the x-axis
        var rotation = new THREE.Matrix4()
        .makeRotationAxis(new THREE.Vector3(1,0,0), 1.57);

        // Apply rotation to the hotspot so it "sits flat below the camera"
        sprite.rotation.setFromRotationMatrix(rotation);

        scene.add(sprite);
    });
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is great. I updated Plunker and I can see the circle is there. I do want to position it within the visible viewport similar to image above. So, it is somewhat on the front texture but attached to the lower part of viewport. Would I need to play around with position.set to achieve it?

Comment: Hi there, if I understand correctly, then you should be able to just offset the hot pot along the z axis that should achieve what you want. If you set the sprite position like this, do you get the desired result? 
`sprite.position.set(0,-5,-5)`

Comment: hi, please see the updates in the answer above where I have made the following adjustment:
`sprite.position.set(0,-5,5);`

Comment: Perfect! Thank you

Comment: I know I accepted the answer but I did run into issue when applying this to my real project. My project is very similar to Plunker example but uses vertex shader and uniforms instead, and also `WebGLRenderer`. When this solution is applied in similar way, I see no image (circle) at all. Do you have any ideas what to check to get the circle visible? I'd be grateful for any hints.

Comment: Are you using a custom vertex shader? If so, you will want to be sure you are transforming vertices via the correct world matrix uniform variable (ie the one that THREE js is sending the transform matrix to, prior to rendering)

Comment: Yes, custom vertex shader is used for panorama. Are you suggesting I apply custom vertex shader to circle image texture as well OR adjust panorama uniform variables and shader?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174760/discussion-between-dacre-denny-and-vad).